# How to send 1 function variable value to another function in c++

Tags: c++

I am a student of c++.
I want to send void a() function n[a] value to function void b().
as you know function a() will take 5 integers from user I want to send variable n[a] to function void b() and than want to print variable n[a] in function void b().I exactly want to move values of n in b().
please help

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void a();
void b();
int main ()
{
    a();

}

void a()
{
    int a=5;
    int n[a];
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {   
        cin>>n[i];
    }   
}

void b()
{

}
```

Comment: Have `b` accept it as a parameter.

Comment: You're much better off learning programming through a textbook than by asking basic questions here (that are poorly formatted too).

Comment: For clarification: What exactly do you want to print in function `b()`? A single value of the array `n` or the whole array?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi I want to print value of array n.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `std::vector<int>` instead of `int[]`
2. Let `a()` return a value
3. Let `b()` have a parameter

Summed up you have something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> a()
{
    int a = 5;
    std::vector<int> n(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {   
        std::cin >> n[i];
    }

    return n;
}

void b(std::vector<int> n)
{
    // do stuff
}

int main ()
{
    b(a());
}
```

Comment: he said he wanted to pass `n[a]` to b, not `n`.

Comment: @kfsone: the `n` variable is a vector and preferred over an array.  When passing an array, the capacity and size parameters need to be passed also.  With `std::vector`, only one variable needs to be passed.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews but the question is about passing a single integer, not passing an array. Teach a man to fish vs teach a man how to deep-sea-trawl.

Comment: Still there is not a proper answer Which I can implement .I request to any c++ to solve my problem properly .I am using Dev C++ ide.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews based on his comments, I stand corrected, can't remove downvote though. Sorry, Tobi.

Comment: @kfsone: you can remove the downvote by upvoting the answer.

Comment: @FaisalRana Why exactly are you unable to use the above code or code from other answers? What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass your array `n` to your function b from function a, call it as b(a). Here's your code.

```
#include <iostream> using namespace std; 
void a(); 
void b();

int main () {
    a();

}

void a() {
    int a=5;
    int n[a];
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {   
        cin>>n[i];
    }
    b(n)   
}

void b(int n[]) {
    for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
        print n[i] 
}
```

Comment: his question stipulates that he wants to pass `a[n]` to `b`, not the whole array.